# Thought Dropbox was gone, but Arduino IDE kept it running. Search led to Temboo & Arduino Yun. Will it cripple my IDE to cut it out?

Tags: arduino-ide, arduino-yun

Just discovered that long after uninstalling Dropbox the service was still running.  I disabled it in the normal Services control panel.  It turned out to be hiding in /winndows/system32 as dbxsvc.exe

Then went a step further and did this in an Administrator CMD window:

```
cd /windows/system32
attrib -h -s dbxsv*.*
del dbxsvc.exe
copy con dbxsvc.exe
Nyah^Z
attrib +r dbxsvc.exe
```

So that should take care of that.

Upon further system searching (using [Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/)) discovered that Dropbox is used by software called Temboo, which is some kind of cloud-share package for coordinating Arduino Yun applications.

**It turned out that it was the Arduino IDE that kept it running.**

More searching led me here:

[Arduino & Temboo: How It Works](https://temboo.com/arduino/yun/yun-and-temboo)

Excerpt:

> ON YOUR YÚN Your Arduino Yún includes two lightweight software
>   components that make it easy to connect with hundreds of APIs and
>   cloud services from any sketch.
>
> First, there's a small C++ library called Temboo.cpp that comes
>   bundled with the Arduino IDE. When you include this library in a
>   sketch, it provides a streamlined syntax for configuring and invoking
>   calls to run Temboo Choreos.
>
> Behind the scenes, calls to Temboo are routed to a client program that
>   comes packaged with your Linino base image. This client is a Python
>   program that formats the Choreo execution request and uses HTTPS to
>   forward the request to Temboo via the cURL utility.
>
> THE TEMBOO PLATFORM Temboo is a scalable, fault-tolerant environment
>   for running and managing smart code snippets that we call Choreos.
>   Choreos can call APIs, simplify the OAuth process, send email
>   messages, perform encoding, update databases, and lots more. You can
>   even create your own custom Choreos. Temboo automatically generates
>   the sketch code you needed to call these processes, making it simple
>   to get up and running with any service from your Yún.
>
> The request from the Yún's temboo client causes the Choreo specified
>   in your sketch code to be executed on the Temboo platform. In many
>   cases, this means assembling your inputs into the format expected by a
>   third-party API, performing the API interaction, handling errors, and
>   dispatching filtered results back to the Yún via HTTPS. The results
>   are made available to your Arduino sketch by way of Process’s Stream
>   methods.

I only use the standard Arduino IDE and regular Arduino Unos and Nanos.  Sure some are Chinese-made, and some use the CH340 connection type.

### I do not want my system reaching out through the firewall to any cloud-based services, nor do I appreciate that the Arduino IDE thwarted my earlier effort to disable and remove Dropbox.

**I get that it came bundled with the standard Arduino IDE.**

**So my question is whether anyone knows if it will damage anything if I remove this junkware?**

--ADDENDUM - Why to dump Dropbox:

[The Dropbox hack is real](https://www.troyhunt.com/the-dropbox-hack-is-real/)

Excerpt:

> Motherboard reported on what had been rumoured for some time, namely
>   that Dropbox had been hacked.
>
> Not just a little bit hacked and not in
>   that "someone has cobbled together a list of credentials that work on
>   Dropbox" hacked either, but proper hacked to the tune of 68 million
>   records.
>
> Very shortly after, a supporter of Have I been pwned (HIBP)
>   sent over the data which once unzipped, looked like this:
>
> (The Dropbox data across 4 text files)
>
> What we've got here is two files with email address and bcrypt hashes
>   then another two with email addresses and SHA1 hashes. It's a
>   relatively even distribution of the two which appears to represent a
>   transition from the weaker SHA variant to bcrypt's adaptive workload
>   approach at some point in time. Only half the accounts get the "good"
>   algorithm but here's the rub: the bcrypt accounts include the salt
>   whilst the SHA1 accounts don't. It's just as well because it would be
>   a far more trivial exercise to crack the older algorithm but without
>   the salts, it's near impossible.
>
> At first glance the data looks legit and indeed the Motherboard
>   article above quotes a Dropbox employee as confirming it.

Comment: To me it looks like the Temboo website is a gateway to Dropbox. The Yun (and the IDE) have nothing at all to do with communication with Dropbox, nor have any software that can do it. The Yun talks to Temboo. Temboo talks to Dropbox.

Comment: And if you're scared someone may have your password from some arbitrary point in the past, then change your password, as well as on any other sites you used the same password.

Answer (score 1):

There is **no** Dropbox software included with ANY version of the Arduino IDE, nor installed on any Linux based Arduino board.

That is **not** how Temboo and Dropbox work.

You have Temboo as a (source code) library which you can compile into your sketch, and as a user-agent that runs on the Linux portion of the Yùn. That then forwards a request to the Temboo web servers detailing what operations you want to perform on what services.

**It is then the Temboo web servers that connect to Dropbox (or whatever service you want to use) and perform operations on your behalf.**

If you have Dropbox software installed on your computer **it is not the fault of the Arduino IDE.**

Comment: Dropbox was removed months ago.  That's why I was so surprised to see the service running.